# Dictionary has optional key

Tags: ios, swift3, cncontact

I'm having a array of `CNContact` and I sort them with this function:

```
for contact in self.contacts {

   var contactName = contact.organizationName

    let key: String = String(contactName.characters.first).uppercaseString
    if let arrayForLetter = self.contactDictionary[key] {
        self.contactDictionary[key]!.append(contact)
        self.contactDictionary.updateValue(arrayForLetter, forKey: key)
    } else {
        self.contactDictionary.updateValue([contact], forKey: key)
    }
}

self.keys = self.contactDictionary.keys.sort()
```

Where contactDictionary is of type:

```
var contactDictionary: [String: [CNContact]] = [String: [CNContact]]()
var keys: [String] = []
```

Now when I see the contactDictionary when it's filled it works except the key always **`Optional(\"T"\")`** or some other letter of course. But why is it optional? The key in the forloop is not optional so how does this come?

Comment: `first` property of collection is of optional type, so you are getting optional probably here `contactName.characters.first` Check once.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem.

Comment: Ofcourse I would. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first` property of `Collection` is of optional type, So you are getting optional probably here `contactName.characters.first`, if you wrapped it using `if let` or `guard` will solved your issue.

```
if let fc = name.characters.first {
    let key = String(fc).uppercaseString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
for contact in self.contacts {
   var contactName = contact.organizationName

    if let key = String(contactName.characters.first).uppercaseString {
        if let arrayForLetter = self.contactDictionary[key] {
            self.contactDictionary[key]!.append(contact)
            self.contactDictionary.updateValue(arrayForLetter, forKey: key)
        } else {
            self.contactDictionary.updateValue([contact], forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

self.keys = self.contactDictionary.keys.sort()
```