# Comparing string with Optional to non Optional string

Tags: if-statement, swift3

**Are they both equal strings?**

[image]

I tried printing them, following is the response:

[image]

When tried comparing them, it turns out to be `false`

[image]

I cannot understand, though they both letters are same in Arabic, but still it says, they aren't!

Here is a more contextual picture of what's happening:

[image]

Comment: Seems like they should be equal. Then again, it's 5AM and I need sleep

Comment: "Optional" appears to be characters in your string, but you seem to be thinking it is part of the type?

Comment: @CRD, I have updated the question to show how the 'firstLetter' is being initialized. It think, you are talking sense and we can figure it out.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/40692090/6433023

Comment: @CRD, you were right, man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends:

---

This is a non-optional `i`

```
let a = "i" // "i"
```

---

This is an optional `i`

```
let b : String? = "i" // "i"
```

---

`a` and `b` are equal

```
a == b // true
```

---

However this is an optional `i` created with String Interpolation

```
let c = "\(b)" // "Optional("i")"
```

---

Now `a` and `c` are **not** equal

```
a == c // false
```

This comparation is `false` because String Interpolation adds literal `Optional` to the string.

Comment: Wow! Genius. Thanks for the knowledge. Though I had answered the question I asked, but your answer is more precise and knowledgable.

Answer (score 0):

As per CRD's comment, the `Optional` was misleading. It turned out that the seemingly type `Optional` was actually an String. Here is how I changed the code to compare the first letters:

```
for song in allSongs{
   let firstLetter = song.name?.characters.first
   var index = 0
   for letter in sectionTitles{
       if(letter.characters.first == firstLetter){
           break;
       }
       index += 1
   }
   var array = sectionedSongs[index]
   array.append(song)
}
```

Note `sectionedSongs` is just an array of arrays.